# Django: Serialize a ManyToMany relationship with a through argument via a related OneToOne model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So the subject may or may not be contextually accurate but what I do know is it involves all of the above and I'm hitting a wall... I'm looking to get a `Workspace` model's owner URL directly on the `Workspace` something like:

#### Desired Output

```json
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/workspaces/1/",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ws 1",
    "slug": "ws-1",
    "users": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/4/"
    ],
    "owner": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/"
}
```

Models.py

```py
class Workspace(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserModel, through="workspaces.WorkspaceUser", related_name="workspaces")

class WorkspaceUser(models.Mode):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="workspace_users", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workspace = models.ForeignKey( Workspace, related_name="workspace_users",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class WorkspaceOwner(BaseTimeStampedModel):
    workspace_user = models.OneToOneField(WorkspaceUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workspace = models.OneToOneField(Workspace, related_name="owner", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializers.py

```py
class WorkspaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workspace
        fields = ["url", "id", "name", "slug", "users", "owner"]

class WorkspaceUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkspaceUser
        fields = ["url", "id", "user"]

class WorkspaceOwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkspaceOwner
        fields = ["url", "id", "user"]
```

How can I best serialize the `workspace.owner.workspace_user.user` `url` for the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`?

Comment: Does `UserModel` have `url` field?

Comment: No @DavidLu it's a basic `Users` model. `url` is an injected attribute from `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `serializers.SerializerMethodField` to get the url.

```
class WorkspaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Workspace
        fields = ["url", "id", "name", "slug", "users", "owner"]

    def get_users(self, obj):
        cur_request = self.context['request']
        return [UserSerializer(x, context={'request': cur_request}).data['url'] for x in obj.users]

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        cur_request = self.context['request']
        return WorkspaceOwnerSerializer(obj.owner, context={'request': cur_request}).data['url']
```